# Spring integration with Elasticsearch 2.0

Tags: spring, elasticsearch-2.0

Has anyone integrated Spring with Elasticsearch 2.0?

I am not able to get any starting point over it and I am facing issues with dependencies.

I am using: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.pilato.spring/spring-elasticsearch/2.0.0

Comment: From what I can tell at the moment, Spring Data Elasticsearch only supports the 1.x versions, and I'm not seeing any branches for 2.x. I have forked it myself, to experiment, but the jump from 1.7 to 2.x seems to have involved deleting a lot of classes (mostly relating to removing 'filter' classes).

Comment: Thanks Steve for your input